# Get database path

Tags: android, database

Im new to android and I want to create kind of CRUD with SQLite.

I have a `public class DataBaseHelper` which have a constructor:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

and a getter for datebase:

```
public SQLiteDatabase getDataBase() {
    if (dataBase == null) {
        try {
            dataBase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DataBaseHelper.dbName,
                                                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            dataBase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DataBaseHelper.accountTblName + " " +
                                        "(ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                                        ",name TEXT" +
                                        ",address TEXT" +
                                        ",password TEXT)");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e(context.toString(), e.getMessage());

                if (dataBase != null) {
                    dataBase.close();
                }
            }
    }       
    return dataBase;
}
```

If I start a program for the first time - everything seems to be okay. database is null and I create it (with a table). But when I restart my app database is null again and table cannot be created.

I've decided to write a checkDB function, which tries to open a database. But where can I get a path for it? I dont want it to be "hardcoded".

Or may be I'm doing some kind of anti-pattern?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can get path by `context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName)`

Comment: Does it give a String path?? I came to know it returns File. How to get a String?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc `context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName).toString;`

Comment: This has also been around since API level 1. Clever.

Comment: it is toString();

Answer (score 5):

## To get the path of Sqlite data base

here  I am writing two ways to get the path.

**(1) using custom method**

```
public String getDbPath(Context context,String YourDbName)
{
    return context.getDatabasePath(YourDbName).getAbsolutePath();
}
```

**(2) using File class**

```
  File path=context.getDatabasePath("YourDbName");
  String db_path=path.getAbsolutePath();
  Log.i("Path:",db_path);
```

even you will see the both code ...then both code is same,
1st one is the shortcut method to get the database path, and it's occupy the *less memory* compare to second option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getDatabasePath method inside your helper's constructor:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wl.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    public String databasePath = "";    

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        databasePath = context.getDatabasePath("wl.db").getPath();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to access dbs for the app also.  This worked for me:

```
String dbFile;
String[] dbNames = getSherlockActivity().databaseList(); // or ContextWrapper
for (int i = 0; i < dbNames.length; i++) {
    dbFile = getSherlockActivity().getDatabasePath(dbNames[i]).toString();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, dbFile);
}
```

Hope it helps! :-)