# How to retrieve the name of database from a path in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I had a db named test.db located in application directory . I retrieved the path using the method "getPath()" which gives entire path of db . How can I get the name of the db from that path.
I ma receiving path a data\test.db . I need to get only test.db . How can I retrieve the name of the databae only from the path in android.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

used `split()` for string `splitting` like

```
String str=yourpathstring;
String[] str1=str.split("/");
String dbname=str1[1];
```

Comment: gives error as insert missing quote at line str.split("\")

Comment: @Android_programmer_office try back slash str.split("/")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String dbpath="yourdbpath";
    File f = new File(dbpath);
    String dbName = f.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

as explained in another threads you can do so with:

```
 context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName)
```

in your case the name is test.db if I understood well; this is the proper way to do it and I think you'll get the path you expect.

source: [Get database path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810430/get-database-path)

Either way; if you just want to extract the name from the String data\test.db then you can:

```
String path = yourpath;
String dbName = path.substring(path.length - 8, 7)
```

Using Substring this way will always extract the last 7 characters.

source: [Extract substring from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414657/extract-substring-from-a-string)