# Android - Show path to my sqlite database file in a Label

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am reading about Android and about how database is created and stored in application internal storage or sandbox.
Assuming I have created a database named "**people.db**" by calling SQLiteHelper.execSQL(peopleDB), how do I get this database file path and show it in a TextView?

To clarify, I am not asking how to create a database but how to get the path to my database file "people.db"?

```
String peopleDB = "people.db";
```

All I am trying to do is show in a Label where that application storage (or sandbox) is and to show my database location on device.  This is just for personal learning, so I am not concerned about showing this information to the user or anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File dir = getDatabasePath("people.db");
textView1.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

File explorer apps have no acces as its your app' private internal storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can find your created database, named

in

```
//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

Use File explorer of DDMS to navigate to emulator directory.

Comment: I cannot navigate into that directory.  I can go into first data but clicking on 2nd data shows nothing

Comment: Hey, thanks but that is not what I was asking.  Anyways, much appreciated.  The marked answer helped figure out and it turned out the correct path is /data/user/0/package-name/databases/people.db.  However, it turns out I cannot navigate to this location using Android Device Monitor in Android Studio so I posted question re that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440253/android-device-monitor-not-showing-content-of-data-user-where-my-database-is-sto

Answer (score 1):

You can get path by `context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName)`

It is already answered here [Get database path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810430/get-database-path)