# Android Device Monitor not showing content of data/user where my database is stored

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

I am trying to find in Android Device Monitor location of my database on my device (Nexus 6P).

I can print the database file name and path using following

```
File dir = getDatabasePath("people.db");
textView1.setText(dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

And it shows that it is located at this location

```
/data/user/0/package-name/databases/people.db
```

However, if I open Android Device Monitor and click on my device, I can navigate into `data` directory but nothing shows in it.

How do I navigate to the location of my application package or my database in Android Device Monitor or some other tool?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17876731/1083957)?

Comment: Why do you want to navigate to that directory? Just looking?

Comment: Yes, I looked at that azzizbekian but I wonder if I can see it ADM.  and Yes, I just want to look but in ADM